# Javascript mouse-over buttons - links not working in <div>, images not appearing correctly in <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

I am a beginner trying to muddle my way through programming my own business website. I have a page with a number of buttons that are coded with a javascript rollover effect. I have [temporarily uploaded the page](http://redravenwoodwork.com.au/temp/table_test_gazillion.html) to my domain so that you can see what I'm talking about.

Here are the addresses for some links to where I got the rollover script and some info about incorporating them into a webpage: http://www.javascript-fx.com/fade_rollovers/ & http://www.javascript-fx.com/fade_rollovers/general_help/help.html

The buttons were working perfectly well, but when I had them in a table, for the life of me I could not get the height of the table cell right. The background image would tile, and 4px of the background image repeating could be seen at the bottom of the cell.

Then I tried divs and they work beautifully for the image/appearance side of things but now the link doesn't work anymore:

```
      <div style="border: none; background-image: url('spiceracks_off.jpg'); width: 155px; height: 155px;>
            <a href="http://www.redravenwoodwork.com.au"
             onmouseover="JSFX.fadeIn('spiceracks')"
             onmouseout="JSFX.fadeOut('spiceracks')" border="0"><img
             style="border: 0px solid; width: 155px; height: 155px;"
             name="spiceracks" class="imgFader" src="spiceracks_off.jpg"></a></div>
```

Before that it was all more or less the same, simply in `td` tags.

Comment: On all of the `<div>`s in your page, you have missed out an ending `"` to end the style. It should be `<div style="border: none; background-image: url('spiceracks_off.jpg'); width: 155px; height: 155px;">`

Answer (score 3):

Missing closing " at end of div tag style attribute.  I think that will solve your problem.